# CoreData Source and destination attribute types are incompatible

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I did create a xcdatamodel to migrate the attribute (in my case from integer16 to string), yet this error triggers.

Answer (score 1):

This error may happen if you've modified the Model AFTER you've created the xcmappingmodel file. In my case the destination, but i presume this would happen with source too.

It seems that in that case, the xcmappingmodel will simply not be applied, even though xcode still report it as mapping from ModelX to ModelY.